# What prevented Ryan Dahl (creator of Node) to create same concept as Node in Ruby instead of Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js

Maybe I missed something in Ryan Dahl interview here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAc0vQCC6UQ

but historically he was very and still is fond of Ruby. Why couldn't he use Ruby to build the same concept as Node instead of Javascript ? I don't know much about Ruby but doesn't Ruby support all Javascript features like functional programming, closures etc. ?

My question is technical please give as much internal details about Javascript vs Ruby Interpreter as possible.

In the interview he said the problem was in Ruby Interpreter without really explaining. Why wouldn't it be also in Javascript?

Comment: You're asking us to give our opinions why someone else made a decision. That needs to be asked of him doesn't it? Also, "give as much internal details about Javascript vs Ruby Interpreter as possible"? That would require a book.

Comment: @theTinMan my point is : it must not be an opinion, there must be some technical reasons. If you cannot explain something simply as one man said ...

Comment: What do you mean "the same concept as Node"? Async-oriented? And why *must* there be a purely technical reason? Regarding internal details around the interpreters, that's two books: one already exists for MRI, I don't know of an equivalent for a JS implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Very short answer**: Nothing.

**Slightly longer answer**: There is nothing technically preventing the implementation of a non-blocking evented asynchronous I/O library for Ruby. In fact, there are several such libraries, some existed before Node.JS, some were inspired by it. E.g. [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/), [Cool.IO](https://coolio.github.io/), [`Celluloid::IO`](https://celluloid.io/).

**Long answer**: Ruby has a standard library. A very rich one. In particular, Ruby has a very rich I/O library: [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html), [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html), [fileutils](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/), [net/ftp](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/), [net/http](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/), [net/imap](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/), [net/pop](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/pop/rdoc/), [net/smtp](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/), [net/telnet](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/), [resolv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/), [socket](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/), [webrick](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/) and others. All of them are blocking. None of them are evented. All of them are synchronous.

ECMAScript, OTOH, has a very poor standard library. When Node.JS started, it was practically non-existent. Now, in [ECMAScript 2015](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), there is a little bit, but it's all data structures, no I/O. Even ES2015 does not have a single I/O function.

This allowed Ryan Dahl to start completely from scratch. Since every tiny little bit of I/O library had to be newly written anyway, it could be written from the ground up to be asynchronous, non-blocking, evented.
And, since the DOM API is mostly evented, ECMAScript programmers were already used to programming in this style!

Whereas in Ruby, one would not only have to throw away all existing I/O library code, you'd also have to retrain all programmers!

Comment: Your answer satisfies me : I wanna learn Ruby but was a bit confused and wondered if it was worth compared to Javascript which I know much better. Still in the interview he said the problem was in Ruby Interpreter without really explaining. Why wouldn't it be also in Javascript?

Comment: Which Ruby implementation are you talking about? There are about 5-7 production-ready implementations plus about 10-20 in various stages of abandonment, development, research, experimentation, prototyping, and planning. And which ECMAScript implementation are you talking about? There are about 10 production-ready implementations plus another 10 or so non production-ready. Without saying which implementation(s) (and also which version(s), since e.g. Rubinius has had several substantial re-writes in its history) you are talking about, it's impossible to answer. Also, which "problem"?

Comment: @user310291 What does learning Ruby have to do with whatever implementation question you're asking? What "problem" in the interpreter? MRI isn't an appropriate solution in some problem spaces, but that's a separate discussion.